# How to provide Prometheus configuration in Amazon EC2 container

Tags: amazon-ec2, prometheus

I have Prometheus container running in EC2 instance and also have ESF mounted in the container as follows:

```
/mount/efs
```

In the Prometheus documentation the way to provide my own configuration is to either bind-mount my `prometheus.yml` from the host by running:

```
docker run \
    -p 9090:9090 \
    -v /tmp/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    prom/prometheus
```

or use an additional volume for the config:

```
docker run \
    -p 9090:9090 \
    -v /path/to/config:/etc/prometheus \
    prom/prometheus
```

I tried selecting my EFS as mount point and setting the container path `/mount/efs:/etc/prometheus` but I get the error:

```
CannotCreateContainerError: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /etc/prometheus
```

Can anyone please help me do this from the EC2 task or any other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution:

The EFS has to be mounted as `/etc/prometheus` and the `prometheus.yml` file is to be put in the root of EFS